# How to track an external JSON file for a change

Tags: javascript, json, api, push

I am currently checking this file: https://api.steampowered.com/IEconService/GetTradeOffers/v1/?key=700D84417970EEAE593ACB8BE455B16E&format=json&get_sent_offers=1 for a change every 5 seconds but Is there any sort of way that I can get notified E.g. a post request when this website changes? I had a look at google push notifications but It seems that it only works for their own api's not external api's

Comment: no, that would be something the site itself has to offer/perform. you can fetch just the HEAD and examine the Last-Modified, ETag, or Content-Length headers to spot changes without refetching the data

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll ask the api providers if they offer such a service. So if they say no, is there no way at all that this could cause I really don't want to be polling every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what do you mean by `getting notified`.

If you want to get an email when the page changes you can use something like this [Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visualping/pemhgklkefakciniebenbfclihhmmfcd)

If you mean it in an programmatically way, then you will have to GET the JSON object from the URL every 5 sec and compare it to the previous version, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript) regarding the compare part.

Comment: By getting notified, I want the service to send a POST request to a url that I specify. E.g. if I was tracking this JSON file: someoneswebsite.com/api/randomjson for a change then when it changes, it would automatically send a POST request to my website E.g. mywebsite.com/APIprotected/newnotification
EDIT: Is google push notifications what I am looking for?

Comment: @mre12345 What you're describing is typically called a `webhook`. If you they provide something like that it will probably be called that.

Comment: ok thanks!, I'll check if the providers of the api provide a webhook